# "Проходной балл" Как ускорить работу кода и устранить недоработку?

Tags: c++, инспекция-кода, олимпиада

Помогите разобраться где может быть недоработка и каким образом можно ускорить работу кода?

[image: задание]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

struct Student
{
    char fam[20];
    char name[20];

    int howMOc = 0; //как много оценок(размер для массива *ocenki )
    int* ocenki; //помещаем
    double srBal = 0;
};

int main()
{
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
    setlocale(0, "rus");
    int howMStud = -1;
    int howMSubj;
    int pasScore = -1; //прох балл
    cin >> howMStud;

    if ((howMStud > 10000) || (howMStud < 1)) exit(0);

    Student* postup = new Student[howMStud];

    for (int i = 0; i < howMStud; i++)
    {
        cin >> postup[i].fam;
        cin >> postup[i].name;
        cin >> howMSubj;

        if ((howMSubj > 50) || (howMSubj < 1)) exit(0);

        postup[i].howMOc = howMSubj;
        postup[i].ocenki = new int[howMSubj];

        for (int j = 0; j < howMSubj; j++)
        {
            cin >> postup[i].ocenki[j];
            postup[i].srBal += postup[i].ocenki[j];
        }//for j

        postup[i].srBal = postup[i].srBal / howMSubj;
    }//for i

    cin >> pasScore;

    //Вывод
    for (int i = 0; i < howMStud; i++)
    {
        if (postup[i].srBal >= pasScore)
        {
            cout << postup[i].fam << " " << postup[i].name;
            cout << endl;
        }//end if
    }//end i

    //system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[image: test]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Из того что я вижу в этом коде:

1. (WA) при вычислении среднего от 50: 10^9 10^9 ... 10^9 вы получите целочисленное переполнение, рекомендую использовать тип long long (у вас может и 64 бита но не факт что там так же).
2. (TL) работа с cin/cout оочень медленная. Есть разные способы исправить это, можете читать через scanf/printf, можно использовать магические строки

   cout.tie(0);
   iostream::sync_with_stdio(0);

рекомендую статью http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/5217?locale=ru (адаптация под олимпиады).

3. (WA/UB) размер строки 20 символов, но не 21 (а нуль символ?)
4. Отвыкайте использовать динамическую память на олимпиадах без реальной необходимости, лучше задать массив сразу размера 10.000 и всё. Больше не меньше.
5. (ML) не храните массив с оценками только само среднее значение, массив используйте общий для всех студентов.

Так код с виду рабочий.

Comment: 3. Так размер массива на 20 символов

Comment: @VladislavSolopov да 20 символов, а куда 0 символ строки запихать? Вы же понимаете что такое char *?

Comment: @VladislavSolopov \0(null-байт) в конце строки всегда есть :D

Comment: @pavel не совсем вас понимаю. 
В массиве выделил место для 20 символов.
Индексом читаем с 0 -до 19 (в сумме 20)

Comment: Про нулбайт еще не слышал. Спасибо, разобрался -WA пропала

Comment: ну осталось чтение нормально сделать и должно работать

Comment: @pavel 1,3,4-реализовал, ошибка на месте. В 5 осталось сделать массив средних баллов. 
2. Если можно, немного опишите ваши "магические строчки"? :)

Comment: @VladislavSolopov просто напишите их в начале программы и не думайте :). и ещё <<endl замените на <<"/n";

Comment: @pavel Это магия D:
Спасибо! Теперь "ОК"
Намекните, что  произошло?!)

Comment: @VladislavSolopov статью читайте) если кратко то отключили синхронизацию с scanf/printf

Comment: Что касается фокусов с tie и sync_with..., то с VC++, по крайней мере 2015, они не проходят - хронометрировал, никаких отличий... Вот printf вместо cout - заметно круче...

Comment: @Harry для VC чуть другая магия к примеру `#define _CRT_DISABLE_PERFCRIT_LOCKS`

Comment: @pavel Которая точно так же не работает :) По крайней мере не работает с printf. Я выводил числа от 0 до 100000 через cout - примерно 17800 мс, через printf - 7180. Добавление к printf этого _CRT_DISABLE_... дало 7146 - это по сути в пределах погрешности.

Comment: @Harry это майскорософт... в статье там магия какае-то тестировать надо)

Comment: @pavel Я тестировал :( Это вообще больное место у MS - по выводу на консоль их обставляют все, даже такая древность, как Watcom...

Answer (score 4):

Откровенно говоря, странно, что проблема **по времени**. Если это на e-olymp, то там же дают целую секунду - это же вечность :) Вот этот код просвистел на ура:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct Data
{
    char name[48];
    unsigned int cnt;
    unsigned int avg;
    unsigned int rem;
    Data():cnt(0),avg(0),rem(0){};
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    vector<Data> ds;

    int N = 0;
    ifstream in("input.txt");
    in >> N;
    string s;
    s.reserve(24);
    ds.reserve(N);
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        Data d;
        in >> s;
        strcpy(d.name,s.c_str());
        in >> s;
        strcat(d.name," ");
        strcat(d.name,s.c_str());
        in >> d.cnt;
        for(int j = 0; j < d.cnt; ++j)
        {
            unsigned int v;
            in >> v;
            d.rem += v%d.cnt;
            d.avg += v/d.cnt;
        }
        ds.push_back(d);
    }
    int K;
    in >> K;
    ofstream out("output.txt");
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        if (ds[i].avg + ds[i].rem/ds[i].cnt >= K)
            out << ds[i].name << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Сразу же можно заметить, что не нужно в принципе выделять память для хранения структур. Получите сначала проходной балл, а потом в цикле проверяйте для каждого имени.

Comment: Как можно прочесть последнее значение для проверки?

Comment: Либо "вхолостую" в цикле "отмотать" n строчек, а потом fseek-ом вернуться, либо (это лучше и быстрее) сразу сделать fseek в конец и идти в обратную сторону до `\n` (это будет последний перевод строки), то есть со следующей позиции начнется проходной балл.

Comment: Ещё ускорение (как я думаю) - сразу прочитать весь файл в память. Ограничение 64Мб не проблема (не думаю, что в тестах есть настолько большой файл). Самое медленное обычно - это ввод/вывод. И, как я думаю, будет быстрее, если все прочитать сразу. Когда занимался олимпиадными задачами - так всегда делал.

Comment: выходит, добавить:
fseek(fopen("test.txt”,”r+”),1,'\n');
?

Comment: @VladislavSolopov `fseek(file, 0, SEEK_CUR)` Далее выполнять `fseek(file, -1, SEEK_SET)` до тех пор, пока `fread` не даст `\n'

Comment: во втором варианте вы подразумеваете поместить весь файл в строку, а потом по разделителю порезать и поместить в нужные поля?

Comment: Можно ссылку на задачу (это в сети где-то, как я понял, с возможностью онлайн-проверки). Даже интересно пройти)) Заодно код могу скинуть.

Comment: @VladislavSolopov да, все в строку, а потом уже с ней работать

Comment: @Алексей_Саровский это университетский сайт. К сожалению, у вас нет доступа

Comment: @VladislavSolopov в общем, я бы сделал так: 1) Прочитать весь файл в строчку; 2) Найти в конце строки этот самый проходной балл; 3) пробежать по строкам (по \n) в цикле и там уже смотреть, выводить или нет это имя.